# How to merge two pandas dataframe based on string search in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 below dataframes. I would like to merge both dataframes on "Item" column and below is my expected output and Code so far. However, below `pandas` code is displaying duplicate rows as shown below. Not sure what is wrong with the code ? I am thinking may be I have to do string search on the "Item"column and then merge the dataframe. However, I am not sure how to achieve this ? Please provide explanation with your code.

Thanks in advance for your time!

**1st Dataframe**

```
Item               ID
ABC                1
ABC                2
ABC                3
CD                 12
EF                 11
```

**2nd DataFrame**

```
Name      Item         Price
Name1     ABC           123.00
Name2     ABC           110
Name 3    ABC           100
Name4      CD           50
```

**Expected Output**

```
Name      Item        ID     Price
Name1     ABC          1    123.00
Name2     ABC          2     110
Name 3    ABC          3     100
 Name4    CD           12    50
```

**Code**

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on="Item",how='outer')
```

**Above code displays below output**

```
    Item    ID  Name    Price
0   ABC 1   Name1   123.0
1   ABC 1   Name2   110.0
2   ABC 1   Name3   100.0
3   ABC 2   Name1   123.0
4   ABC 2   Name2   110.0
5   ABC 2   Name3   100.0
6   ABC 3   Name1   123.0
7   ABC 3   Name2   110.0
8   ABC 3   Name3   100.0
9   CD  12  Name4   50.0
10  EF  11  NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate `Item` with [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) in each DataFrame to allow for the positional alignment within the merge:

```
df3 = pd.merge(
    df1, df2,
    left_on=['Item', df1.groupby('Item').cumcount()],
    right_on=['Item', df2.groupby('Item').cumcount()]
)
```

`df3`:

```
  Item  key_1  ID    Name  Price
0  ABC      0   1   Name1  123.0
1  ABC      1   2   Name2  110.0
2  ABC      2   3  Name 3  100.0
3   CD      0  12   Name4   50.0
```

[`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) can be added to remove this added merge key column:

```
df3 = pd.merge(
    df1, df2,
    left_on=['Item', df1.groupby('Item').cumcount()],
    right_on=['Item', df2.groupby('Item').cumcount()]
).drop(columns='key_1')
```

`df3`:

```
  Item  ID    Name  Price
0  ABC   1   Name1  123.0
1  ABC   2   Name2  110.0
2  ABC   3  Name 3  100.0
3   CD  12   Name4   50.0
```

---

Setup and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Item': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'CD', 'EF'],
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 12, 11]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name 3', 'Name4'],
    'Item': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'CD'],
    'Price': [123.00, 110, 100, 50]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method I can come up with is to add another column to your input dataframes which mimics the index [0, 1, 2, 3...]. This produces a unique entry even when the 'Item' is duplicated, and leads to a correct merge.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

A = [[1, 2, 3, 4], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
B = [[10, 20, 30, 40], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], [0, 1, 2, 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(A).T
df.columns = ['Val', 'ID', 'IDX']
print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(B).T
df2.columns = ['Other', 'ID', 'IDX']
print(df2)

M = pd.merge(df, df2)
print(M)
```