# Merge two python dataframes and avoid adding same match twice before moving to the next row

Tags: python, pandas

For `pandas.merge(df1, df2, on='Col_4')` will operate by **inner join** by default which will take rows on the shared columns that have the exact values in these shared columns.

**Question**: Let us say we have a 4 rows in first `df1` and 3 rows in `df2`. So if all values in the shared columns are the same, then the first row will be added 4 times since we have, so we will have 10 rows for each row from dataframe1. In total, we will have 12 rows.

**Problem**: Is there a way to stop once we find a first match between the first and the second dataframe and move to the second row in the first dataframe please? **However**, we can not add the same match added to row 1 in `df1` twice. So, suppose row 1 of `df1` got matched to row 1 in `df2` based on same value in shared column `col_4`, then the second row in `df1` must be matched with second row of `df2`.

[image]

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ID':[1,2,3,5,9],
        'col_1': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'col_2':[6,7,8,9,10],
        'col_3':[11,12,13,14,15],
        'col_4':['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ID':[1,1,3,5],
        'col_1': [8,9,10,11],
        'col_2':[12,13,15,17],
        'col_3':[12,13,14,15],
        'col_4':['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']
    }
)

pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col_4')
```

So, as below, how to stop please at first match as red rectangle show where we stop once we find a match from df1 to df2 based on shared column `col_4` please? Output should be based on below figure please:

[image]

Results in dictionary format:

```
{'ID_x': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 2,
  5: 2,
  6: 2,
  7: 2,
  8: 3,
  9: 3,
  10: 3,
  11: 3,
  12: 5,
  13: 5,
  14: 5,
  15: 5,
  16: 9,
  17: 9,
  18: 9,
  19: 9},
 'col_1_x': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 2,
  5: 2,
  6: 2,
  7: 2,
  8: 3,
  9: 3,
  10: 3,
  11: 3,
  12: 4,
  13: 4,
  14: 4,
  15: 4,
  16: 5,
  17: 5,
  18: 5,
  19: 5},
 'col_2_x': {0: 6,
  1: 6,
  2: 6,
  3: 6,
  4: 7,
  5: 7,
  6: 7,
  7: 7,
  8: 8,
  9: 8,
  10: 8,
  11: 8,
  12: 9,
  13: 9,
  14: 9,
  15: 9,
  16: 10,
  17: 10,
  18: 10,
  19: 10},
 'col_3_x': {0: 11,
  1: 11,
  2: 11,
  3: 11,
  4: 12,
  5: 12,
  6: 12,
  7: 12,
  8: 13,
  9: 13,
  10: 13,
  11: 13,
  12: 14,
  13: 14,
  14: 14,
  15: 14,
  16: 15,
  17: 15,
  18: 15,
  19: 15},
 'col_4': {0: 'apple',
  1: 'apple',
  2: 'apple',
  3: 'apple',
  4: 'apple',
  5: 'apple',
  6: 'apple',
  7: 'apple',
  8: 'apple',
  9: 'apple',
  10: 'apple',
  11: 'apple',
  12: 'apple',
  13: 'apple',
  14: 'apple',
  15: 'apple',
  16: 'apple',
  17: 'apple',
  18: 'apple',
  19: 'apple'},
 'ID_y': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 3,
  3: 5,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 3,
  7: 5,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 3,
  11: 5,
  12: 1,
  13: 1,
  14: 3,
  15: 5,
  16: 1,
  17: 1,
  18: 3,
  19: 5},
 'col_1_y': {0: 8,
  1: 9,
  2: 10,
  3: 11,
  4: 8,
  5: 9,
  6: 10,
  7: 11,
  8: 8,
  9: 9,
  10: 10,
  11: 11,
  12: 8,
  13: 9,
  14: 10,
  15: 11,
  16: 8,
  17: 9,
  18: 10,
  19: 11},
 'col_2_y': {0: 12,
  1: 13,
  2: 15,
  3: 17,
  4: 12,
  5: 13,
  6: 15,
  7: 17,
  8: 12,
  9: 13,
  10: 15,
  11: 17,
  12: 12,
  13: 13,
  14: 15,
  15: 17,
  16: 12,
  17: 13,
  18: 15,
  19: 17},
 'col_3_y': {0: 12,
  1: 13,
  2: 14,
  3: 15,
  4: 12,
  5: 13,
  6: 14,
  7: 15,
  8: 12,
  9: 13,
  10: 14,
  11: 15,
  12: 12,
  13: 13,
  14: 14,
  15: 15,
  16: 12,
  17: 13,
  18: 14,
  19: 15}}
```

**Edit**: if first row from `df1` got matched with first row from `df2`, then the second row from `df1` **cannot** be matched again with first row of `df2` but it should be matched with the second row from `df2` if there is a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a serial number `serial` for each group of same value of `col_4` in each of `df1` and `df2`.  Then, merge by `col_4` and this serial number `serial`, as follows:

We generate the serial number by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1['serial'] = df1.groupby('col_4').cumcount()

df2['serial'] = df2.groupby('col_4').cumcount()

df1.merge(df2, on=['col_4', 'serial'])
```

**Result:**

```
   ID_x  col_1_x  col_2_x  col_3_x  col_4  serial  ID_y  col_1_y  col_2_y  col_3_y
0     1        1        6       11  apple       0     1        8       12       12
1     2        2        7       12  apple       1     1        9       13       13
2     3        3        8       13  apple       2     3       10       15       14
3     5        4        9       14  apple       3     5       11       17       15
```

Optionally, you can further remove this serial number column `serial`, as follows:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['col_4', 'serial']).drop('serial', axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
   ID_x  col_1_x  col_2_x  col_3_x  col_4  ID_y  col_1_y  col_2_y  col_3_y
0     1        1        6       11  apple     1        8       12       12
1     2        2        7       12  apple     1        9       13       13
2     3        3        8       13  apple     3       10       15       14
3     5        4        9       14  apple     5       11       17       15
```

### Edit

You can also simplify the codes by incorporating the generations of serial numbers into the step of `.merge()`, as follows:   (Thanks for the suggestion by @HenryEcker)

```
df1.merge(df2, 
          left_on=['col_4', df1.groupby('col_4').cumcount()],
          right_on=['col_4', df2.groupby('col_4').cumcount()]
          ).drop('key_1', axis=1)
```

Comment: You can also pass the series directly to merge instead of adding columns to df1 and df2 if needed. Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69503179/15497888)

Comment: @HenryEcker  Wow, that's a good tricks.  Thanks!  :-)

Comment: @SeaBean. How to learn such complex operations please? Most found in books are trivial operations? Any source for a book please to learn like your statements?

Comment: @Avra  I learned most of the complex and tricky operations by answering questions here and also learned from others here.  For a book, I think the book by Wes McKinney is very good:  Python for Data Analysis - Data Wrangling with Pandas, NumPy, and IPython 2nd Ed (2017)

Comment: @SeaBean. It took me 3 days to understand your solution. Thanks again. I see now why GroupBy.cumcount is used! It adds more restriction so rows from both tables get matched by merge only if theyr `col_4` equals and also their `serial` equals! Really appreciated.

Comment: @Avra  I also appreciate much your good attitude to learn and understand everything. Surely you are in the right path to pick out the knowledges quickly and comprehensively.  Keep it up and enjoy the learning process! 

Comment: @SeaBean. Hello Sea, I have similar issue I posted here if you would like to see it. Thanks. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500734/matching-different-items-from-two-columns