# Matching different items from two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have the following data frame before and after (goal). I would like to make sure that no two column values are together (if they have the same label vale from `Label` column in data frame). Below is a sample of 4 rows where `(1, 10)` together because they have the same label, but I would like the opposite such that `Column 1` and `Column 2` must not have the same label so `1` can be associated with either `11` or `13` and same for others.

Also, the same value from `column 1` can not not be paired with more than one different item from `column 2` based on `Label 1` value, so I would just assume we get `(1,11)` after operation and not `(1, 11)` and `(1,13)` rows.

[image]

My approach is as follows. I used `groupby('Label')cumcount()` to add another column to solve first issue  of having two matches `(1, 11)` and `(1,13)`, I can only have one `(1, 11)` for example, but I am not sure how to do the other, i.e., to to match rows that have different `Label` values together with constraint of having at most one match.

### Sample

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Column1': [1,2,3,4],
        'Column2':[10,11,12,13],
        'Label':['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange']
    }
)

target = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Column1': [1,2,3,4],
        'Column2':[11,10,13,12],
        'Label':['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange']
    }
)
```

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble following your logic. Could `(1, 13)` also be the first row?

Comment: @DerekO. Yes Derek. That is possible, but I am just looking for one match between columns `col 1` and `col 2` such that their labels are different, which is enough. So we cab only have either `(1, 13)` or `(1, 11)` but not bath in the target data frame. I though that `cumcount` might solve the first issue of having either `(1, 13)` or `(1, 11)`.

Comment: Does this question/answer help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69518646/merge-two-python-dataframes-and-avoid-adding-same-match-twice-before-moving-to-t

Comment: @Paul. Thank you. That is also my question, but that one is different as it's supposed to match rows from two columns such that we avoid repetition and also we match rows based on shared columns that have common values. Here I would like to do the opposite by matching rows where their `Label` are different such that I haver one match at most.

Answer (score 0):

Bruteforce answer that needs `O(n^2)`, still working to get better one:

```
for i in range(len(df1_col1)):
    for j in range(len(df1_col2)) :
        if((df1_col1["Label"].iloc[i] != df1_col2["Label"].iloc[j]) and (df1_col2["Label"].iloc[j] != "NaN")):
            match = {'Column1': df1_col1["Column1"].iloc[i], 'Column2': df1_col2["Column2"].iloc[j]}
            print(match)
            df1_col2["Label"].iloc[j] = "NaN"
            result.append(match, ignore_index=True)
            break
```